# Rest api that after a post returns a value

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this post api:

```
@PostMapping
public void connect(@RequestBody String data)
{
    int result = service.connect(data);
}
```

I want to send back the result to whomever called this REST api. How can I do it? Can I send a int or a whole Object in Json format? I would like both if possible.

Comment: change the return type of method to `int` and add return statement `return result`

Comment: Got it, why the down vote?

Comment: @deadpool, thank you, I honestly thought it would be more complex with SpringBoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method return type to `int`, and simply return `result`. Spring Boot handles JSON serialization for you. You can return anything, as long as it's serializable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: Actually, serialization has nothing to do here. Spring mvc doesn’t use serialization when generating responses. With the default settings, the response body generated for an int will be a text representation of the number.

Comment: @MateuszStefek the serialized version of an integer is a string literal containing the integer. It’s still serialization. And yes, Spring MVC does serialize POJO responses automatically.